# Microsoft Access and SharePoint

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, sharepoint-online

Microsoft announced that SharePoint will no longer support Access web apps. I am trying to build a relational database, and allow users to view and update the database through SharePoint.

Since I can't use Access anymore, what are my alternatives?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for recommendations or lists of things aren't really acceptable here. You may want to take a few minutes to go through the [tour] and review the [help] pages, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If all you require is the ability to make updates to the tables that comprise your database, you can still use SharePoint lists to do that and use the desktop Access client to achieve a relational database.